# Group continuous notifications with the same value in a field

Tags: php, mysql

How can I group notifications that have the same value in the "type" and "message_id" columns and are continuous?
The structure of my "notifications" table is this:

> [id | author | datetime | type | message_id | notification_to]

I've tried with the `GROUP BY` function but this groups all the records, not just the ones that are continuous with each other.

Right now all I have is a simple query, since with `GROUP BY` I have not achieved anything:

```
$notifications = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE notification_to = '$session_row_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20", $connection);
```

And to list the records:

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($notifications)) { ... }
```

This is what I have now:

```
USER1 followed you
USER2 followed you
USER3 shared your message[ID:10]
USER4 followed you
USER5 shared your message[ID:20]
USER6 shared your message[ID:20]
USER7 shared your message[ID:30]
```

And what I want to get is this:

```
USER1 and 1 more followed you
USER3 shared your message[ID:10]
USER4 followed you
USER5 and 1 more shared your message[ID:20]
USER7 shared your message[ID:30]
```

Like Twitter notifications: [view screenshot](http://uigarage.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/tumblr_o1mucflxii1ul8y65o1_1280-1.jpg)

Comment: I think you should tag this question as sql or mysql aswell, also show us some code, what have you tried? What are you expecting? What are you getting? ..

Comment: Right now all I have is a simple query, since with GROUP BY I have not achieved anything. I've this: $notifications = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE notification_to = '$session_row_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20", $connection);

Comment: And to list the records: while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($notifications)) { ... }

Comment: What do you mean by "group"? Do you want them grouped together in arrays? Can you show us an example of the data and how you'd like the final structure to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$notifications = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE notification_to = '$session_row_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20", $connection);

$last_notification = false;
$grouped_notifications = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($notifications)) {
    if($last_notification && $row['message_id'] == $last_notification['message_id'] && $row['type'] == $last_notification['type']){
        $last_notification['plus']++;
    }else{
        $row['plus'] = 0;
        $grouped_notifications[] = $row;
        $last_notification = &$grouped_notifications[count($grouped_notifications)-1];
    }
}

foreach($grouped_notifications as $notification){
    echo $notification['author'];
    if($notification['plus']>0){
        echo ' and '.$notification['plus'].' more';
    }
    echo ' has '.$notification['type'];
}
```

We get all notifications, and group them using PHP (it's easier). We check if the last notification we handled is the same as the current one, if so, we add one to the users amount. Else we create a new notification and link it on the last_notification.

After that, we simply echo our notifications checking if there was more than 1 user... I have simply echo'd the type as you omitted to tell us what variable should be used or meant or anything.

Comment: Thanks so much! I just tested your code and it seems to work correctly.

Comment: It works perfect. How do I now to show all the authors that have been grouped? Now only the last one, and I wanted to show the others too.

Comment: You never said you wanted to show the others... You should add them to a list "others" or something and use that.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not explain myself well. I needed other users to display their profile pictures.

Comment: I've already got it. First, I am adding each user name to a `$grouped_authors` variable and separating them with commas. Then I create the array with `explode(',', $grouped_authors)` and finally I apply a function to each element of the array with `foreach`.

Comment: as long as they do not have commas in their name it's gonna work.

Comment: The values of ​​`$grouped_authors` are the user IDs, so there will be no commas in this field.